# Как использовать .animate в react?

Tags: reactjs

Есть вот такая анимация на js

```
const block = document.getElementById("block")
block.animate([
  // keyframes
  { transform: 'translate3D(0, 0, 0)' },
  { transform: `translate3D(1000px, 0, 0)` }
], {
  // timing options
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: Infinity
})
```

Каким образом функцию `animate` можно использовать в react?

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/animation.html

Comment: @DmitryKozlov там используются css анимации, мне же нужно что-то аналогичное примеру из вопроса